# How to give a function as a input for s3 location in hive script

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, user-defined-functions

I am trying to do achieve this;

```
location/11.11
location/12.11
location/13.11
```

In order to do that , i have tried many things and couldn't make it happen.
Now i have an Udf hive function which returns me the location of s3 table, but i am facing with an error ;

> ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'LOCATION'
>   'datenow' '(' LOCATION datenow(); NoViableAltException(143@[])

This is my hive script , i have two external tables.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION datenow AS 'LocationUrlGenerator';
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS s3( file Array<String>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
LOCATION datenow();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it like that ,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE S3
PARTITION(time)
SELECT  func(json),from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd') AS time FROM tracksTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`LOCATION`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/TruncateTable) accepts a string, not an UDF. The Language Manual si a bit unclear because it only specifies `[LOCATION hdfs_path]` and leaves `hdfs_path` undefined, but it can only be an URL location path, a string. In general UDFs are not acceptable in DDL context.

Build a script with any text tool of choice and run that script.